# Metaanalysis - how big should be the ICC (Intracluster correlation coefficient)?

Tags: meta-analysis, intraclass-correlation

The background is a metaanalysis of cluster randomised clinical studies. The included studies report no ICC for final values, the chosen ICC for the calculations was 0,02. Similar studies in the same field do not exist.

1. Is an ICC of 0,02 a "good" choice to correct the values?
2. Are there any rules, references to follow when choosing the ICC for a metaanalysis? Other than using similar studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on what the clusters are, what the intervention is and who the participants are. There have been a number of publications which have tried to summarise ICC values and there are about ten references in a recent paper by Rutterford and colleagues which is currently on-line pre-publication. It is open access so freely available.

@article{rutterford,
   author = {Rutterford, C and Copas, A and Eldridge, S},
   title = {Methods for sample size determination in cluster
      randomised trials},
   journal = {International Journal of Epidemiology},
   year = {??},
   volume = {??},
   pages = {??},
   keywords = {trials, cluster randomisation, sample size}
}

Hopefully you will find something there which fits your requirements.